# Suitability of an F test for proportion data?

Tags: time-series, proportion, f-statistic

I'm reading a paper where the authors have 3 related time series based on proportion data. They test for a change in these proportions by using an F test and state that this allows them to check whether the slopes differ significantly from zero. This doesn't seem right to me because surely you'd want to check whether each proportion is different from zero not whether any do. Am I missing something here.

Comment: Is there anything going on here that’s specific to the outcome being a proportion? For instance, do you understand why an ANOVA F-test would be run under the cleanest conditions where the groups have Gaussian distributions?

Comment: The proportions are based on the sentiment of news articles (positive, neutral or negative) and that's what's being assessed for a change over time. They report a p-value for each proportion so I presume they did it separately. It's under review so I can't link directly.